# Display Contents In TableView After Parsing From a File stored in Documents Folder - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a file called as "hhhh.txt" which has the following contents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
            <key>aa</key>
            <string>2012-06-26 14:25:43</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>bb</key>
            <string>2012-06-26 14:25:49</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>cc</key>
            <string>2012-06-26 14:25:51</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I also have a button called as "Show History". On clicking it, I want to display the names of keys i.e. "aa", "bb", "cc" in tableview in a small window.

Currently, I have written the following lines of code in "showHistoryPressed" function of .m file ::

```
NSString *hisDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *historyFilePath = [hisDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hhhh.txt"];
```

I want to read the hhhh.txt file and then parse the keys .. and then subsequently display their names in a tableView on the click of the button of "show history".

How should I proceed now ?? Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:historyFilePath ];
```

will be your array containing dictionaries.

For getting all keys you can have this

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
  [keys addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeys]];
}
```

Comment: how should I display those keys in TableView which pops up on the clicking of the button showHistory ??

Comment: the tutorial was not much of help .. :-/

Comment: you have the array your rows count is equal to array count and cell.text = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arrayOfDictionary = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:historyFilePath ];
```

above code ill fetch the array of dictionaries present in the text file

now u can get the string associated with the key from the dictionary as below

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayOfDictionary) 
{
  [strings addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeys]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:historyFilePath ];

NSMutableArray *tableContentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) {
  [tableContentArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"key"]];
}

now load your table view with this tableContentArray
```

hope this will help u ..

Comment: how should I display the contents of tableContentArray in TableView which pops up on the clicking of the button showHistory ??

Comment: return the number of row as the count of this array ...
and cell.titleLabel.text = [tableContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

simple .. if your not able to find this array try to allocate this array in appdelegate and make it property and access it ....